# Select lines that contain an word, but do not contain another word (HTML tags)

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have this 2 html tags in more than 2000 html pages:

`<td><span class="den_articol"><a href="my-link.html" class="linkMare">My Link</a></span></td>`

`<td><span class="den_articol"><a href="https://my-link.html" class="linkMare">My Link</a></span></td>`

I want to use a regex solution, to find only those rows that contains **"den_articol"** but does not contains **"https"**:

So, the search result should be the first of my example:

`<td><span class="den_articol"><a href="my-link.html" class="linkMare">My Link</a></span></td>`

I made a regex, but is not too good, maybe someone has a better solution:

`(.*?den_articol")(.+?)(?!https://).*`

Answer (score 0):

SEARCH:

`(<td><span class="den_articol">).*(<a .*?href=")(?!https://)(.+?").*`

REPLACE BY:

`(LEAVE EMPTY)`